# SIGSEGV run-time error while taking space seperated inputs

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, runtime-error

I was trying to solve my first problem on linked list as I had just learned the concept. I kept getting a **Runtime Error - SIGSEGV** (*I understand that my program is trying to access some memory address that it is not supposed to*).

```
int n;
cin>>n;
int v[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
     cout<<"\n "<<i<<endl;
    // To be removed, helps check till where the loop ran;
    cin>>v[i];

    cout<<v[i];

}
```

Every time the loop would run till the second last element and after that, in the last loop, it would give the error.

I know this a very basic question but can someone help me, I have been stuck on it for very long now.
[Question Link](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/linked-list/singly-linked-list/practice-problems/algorithm/reversed-linked-list-01b722df/)

Comment: See the linked question. You cannot allocate a runtime-sized array like that using standard C++.

Comment: array subscript can only be used only with constant expression or value..